# Cassandra inconsistency in update / insert

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-services, cassandra

When I try to update data in table with C# using Cassandra driver sometimes records are not getting updated properly, and there are no errors logged.

Surprisingly when I execute the same code again or when I run it with breakpoints records are getting updated.

I tried using prepared statement, batch statement with in `session.Execute()`  and `mapper.Execute()` none of them helped me to resolve the issue.

I referred this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.2/) for update / insert. Is my approach correct and also help me to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: What is the consistency level used by your update query?

Comment: QUORUM, which is been declared in a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are immediately fetching the updated values from Cassandra. We also faced this problem using java driver while testing DB. Try using a `sleep/wait` for ***1-2sec*** between executing and fetching the result.

Comment: ok I'll try to apply this, but still is there any other alternative fix for it.

Comment: Actually, it's not a bug assuming how Cassandra stores its data. In the real world, you do not actually fetch the updated data immediately.  @Sebastian